ATTINY85-20SUR and serial communication
I am trying to use this chip ATtiny85 for serial communication. So my question is, would you recommend using it for serial communication, such as storing names, IDs, data, and last operations? Should I be concerned about the memory? Do you recommend a different chip that robust serial communication?

Serial communication has very little to do with storing data.

asking for recommendations is off topic here because recommendations are just opinions

please ask a focused question about a problem you are trying to solve

These are vague requirements. Define robust serial communications and define your algorithm so that we have insight into if your application is suitable.

Given the ATtiny85 has 8 kB of flash and 512 bytes of ram, optimising memory usage might be important.

ATtiny85 is usually used with its internal clock source, which is not as stable as a standard crystal oscillator, so that may impact serial communications above a certain baud rate. Consult datasheet.
